# php artisan serve error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, serve

I'm trying to launch a Laravel server and I'm getting this error:

> **Warning:** require(C:\Users\Puuter\application\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Puuter\application\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> **Fatal error:** require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Puuter\application\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\Puuter\application\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

As a newbie, I can't figure this out. To make matters worse, I'm using Windows, and the internet seems to be lacking information about anything web development related on Windows.

Now, I have gotten this to work before: I downloaded WAMP, which seemed to fix it then, but didn't now.

Comment: It's looking for the `autoload.php` file in the vendor directory, is that file in there? If not, have you done `composer install`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

In the project path, write from the console:
composer update

And ready

Answer (score 0):

On Puuter folder run:

> composer install